# Width of empty multi-part node segment larger than expected

Tags: tikz-pgf

If I draw the following node, I'd expect to get four squares:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[multibox/.style={draw,
  rectangle split,
  inner sep=0cm,
  rectangle split empty part width=0.3cm,
  rectangle split empty part height=0.3cm}]
\node[multibox] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But the resulting rectangles are wider than expected. What parameter am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from the manual p.450 (v.2.10)

> When split vertically, the rectangle split will observe any minimum width requirements but any minimum height will be ignored. Conversely when split horizontally, minimum height requirements will be observed, but any minimum width will be ignored.

So, following this advice, the following gives 4 squares.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[multibox/.style={draw,
  rectangle split,
  inner sep=0cm,
  minimum width=3mm,
  rectangle split empty part height=3mm}]
\node[multibox] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My guess is that one of the options is for the vertical mode and the other is for the horizontal. However, you provided both in the vertical mode.